# How to change the default title style for sections in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, latex, yaml, knitr, r-markdown

When I write  `# Introducción` into my `.rmd` file, the section title is on the format **1. Introducción** by default. I need something like this:

[image]

I prefer to use only markdown language. Is it possible to change into my YAML header?

Answer (score -1):

If you're ok with some minimal TeX syntax you could try this:

```
----
title: "Title"
author: "Me"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
output:
    pdf_document
----
\chapter{Introducción}
```

This is just a proposal to use the fncychap class, see [here](https://texblog.org/2012/07/03/fancy-latex-chapter-styles/) for some ideas. I couldn't test it here, but you might get an idea.